# Extracting Lens information from a title

Tags: excel-formula

Im having difficulty making a formula.

I want to extract the focal length in one field and the aperture in another field.

The text would be 
Sigma 28-200mm f3.5-5.6 DG Macro, Boxed 5001360

Ideally I want to extract the "28-200mm" into one field and the "f3.5-5.6" into another. The only constants for each would be that the focal lenth always ends in mm and the aperture always starts with f.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the text `Sigma 28-200mm f3.5-5.6 DG Macro, Boxed 5001360` is in `Cell A1` then to get `Focal Length` use the following formula

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,(FIND("mm",A1,1)+1))," ",REPT(" ",LEN(LEFT(A1,(FIND("mm",A1,1)+1))))),LEN(LEFT(A1,(FIND("mm",A1,1)+1)))))
```

To get `Aperture` use below formula

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("f",A1)+1),(FIND(" ",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("f",A1)+1),1)-1))
```

***Note :*** The `FIND` function is case sensitive. If you are looking for a case-insensitive match, use the `SEARCH` function as

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("f",A1)+1),(SEARCH(" ",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("f",A1)+1),1)-1))
```

***Another Note :*** If you have another text/word in the string containing `f` then you may get incorrect result. `FIND` function returns the position of the character occurring first. See `Row 4` in image below

[image]

Another formula to get `Focal Length`

```
=MID(LEFT(A1,(FIND("mm",A1,1)+1)),FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,(FIND("mm",LEFT(A1,(FIND("mm",A1,1)+1)),1)+1))," ","@",LEN(LEFT(A1,(FIND("mm",A1,1)+1)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,(FIND("mm",A1,1)+1))," ",""))))+1,LEN(LEFT(A1,(FIND("mm",A1,1)+1))))
```